# Different hover styling on different labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

```
    self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0); border-style:none;\n"
    "}\n"
    "QLabel#label2 {    \n"
    "   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 120); color: white; text: center; border-style:solid; border- 
    width: 1px; border-top-style: none;\n"
    "}\n"
    "QLabel#label3 {    \n"
    "background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); text: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "QLabel:hover + QLabel#label2{  \n"
    "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 120); color: rgba(255,255,255,255); text: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "QLabel:hover + QLabel#label3 { \n"
    "background-color: rgb(118, 185, 0); color: rgba(255,255,255,255); text: center;\n"
    "}\n")
```

I have two labels (label 1 and 2) and I want them both to be styled differently when any label is hovered over. How can I achieve this? I am using css styling in pyqt5. PS: Both my labels are within my scroll area so changes made in the stylesheet do take effect when run.

Comment: 1. Please be more clear about your requests; 2. Try to format code in a more readable way: I suggest you to use triple quotes (`'''text<linebreak>otherthext'''`) for strings like those; 3. As specified in the [style sheets reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qlabel-widget), QLabel does **not** support the `:hover` pseudo state, so you have to implement it on your own, by subclassing the label, installing an event filter, widget-promoting it or, eventually, monkey patching the label.

Answer (score 0):

You can set accessible name to each of your label: `label.setAccessibleName("label1")`

and target it in the stylesheet like this:

```
QLabel[accessibleName="label1"]{ border: 1px solid red;}
```

You can also set stylesheet for specific a widget like this:

```
widget.setStyleSheet('QLabel:hover{border:1px solid red;}')
```

Also, I would suggest using triple quotes for multiline strings:

```
stylesheet="""QLabel{
                  border:1px solid red;
              }  """
```

Comment: This does let the hover work separately but I want it so both label hover effects are activated if the mouse hovers over one. Is that possible or is there a way to do that? The issue is that both labels have different hover effects but I need them both activated if one is. Thanks for this though, because it did help me clean my stylesheets up. Or have I misunderstood and this does let me do that since when I tried, it didnt activate both.

Comment: Looks like I misread your question but what you want is a signal when a mouse hovers over the label. I am pretty sure the QLabel class does not have such signal. You can look into eventFilters and catch the MouseMove event. See if this post can guide you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050397/eventfilter-on-a-qwidget-with-pyqt4